# call arguments of for loop no matter how they are named

Tags: r, function, loops, for-loop

is it possible to call the `min`, `max` and running variable `i` in a for loop without referencing these objects specifically via their names?

As an example take this for loop

```
for(i in min:max) {
     # do some calculation
}
```

and suppose now I have a function `f` with arguments `mi`, `ma` and `ii`. Then, I want to do

```
for(i in min:max) {
     # do some calculation
     f(mi, ma, ii)
}
```

where `mi = min`, `ma = max` and `i = ii` automatically. That is, the function `f` automatically takes `min`, `max` and `i` as input in the way that it acesses them from the for loop environment.

I hope I made myself clear. However, if anything is confusing please let me know and I will try to clarify it further.

Thank you!

Comment: You're asking if you can just call `f()` without args and have it infer values of `min`, `max`, and `i` from the calling environment?

Comment: Are mi and ma needs to be dynamic?

Comment: exactly! actually no, mi and ma do not need to be dynamic! I mean if it is possible to implement it with dynamic mi and ma, it would alos be great!

Comment: It can be done. I strongly recommend against it: it's sloppy functional programming, indicates bad design, is susceptible to all sorts of problems plaguing reproducibility, troubleshooting can be a counter-intuitive chore, and ... likely many other reasons. A function should "know" only what is explicitly *passed* to it; exceptions are rare and often very useful in meta-programming, not something like this.

Comment: Lacking that, write your `f` function with conditionals such as `if (missing(mi)) mi <- min` and it should work assuming that `min` is available in the calling environment. BTW: this highlights another anti-pattern with your code: naming a variable after a base R function will cause problems when `min` has not been defined: it will find `base::min`, a function, and doing data-stuff on a function typically breaks.

Comment: More reason to avoid this: outside of the `for` loop, all of `i`, `min`, and `max` will still be defined, so calling `f()` outside of the `for` loop seems not intended in your desired workflow here but will still work, and who knows if it will do what you think it should.

Comment: One can possibly mitigate some of it with something like `if (missing(mi)) mi <- get("min", envir = parent.frame(), inherit = FALSE)`.

Comment: Bottom line, though, is that this is very likely an enticing idea up front (for a little lazy interactive R work) but is a really bad idea in so many other ways.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Obviously, the names were chosen this way only for the purpose of demonstration, so the arguments will be named differently. However, I understand the caveats of such an approach and will think about my idea again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a call to `forInfo` *immediately after* the `for` for which information is wanted.  It assumes reasonably well behaved for statement on a line by itself with no spaces within the expression that defines the bounds.

The arguments to `forInfo` are:

- the function containing the `for`
- a unique string that will be searched for.  It must not appear anywhere else in the function
- the environment calling `forInfo`.  The default is usually correct.

The code for `forInfo` and some tests follow.

```
library(gsubfn)

forInfo <- function(fun, mark, env = parent.frame()) {
    b <- format(body(fun))
    x <- strapplyc(b[grep(mark, b)-1], "\\S+") |>
      unlist() |>
      setdiff(c("for", "in", "{"))
    x[1] <- sub("^\\(", "", x[1])
    x[2] <- sub("\\)$", "", x[2])
    list(index = get(x[1], env),
         bounds = range(eval(parse(text = x[2]), env)))
}
   
# test - on each iteration display the value of index and the bounds

f <- function() {

  min <- 1; max <- 3
  for(i in min:max) {
    v <- forInfo(f, "mark1")
    with(v, cat("index:", index, "bounds:", bounds, "\n"))
  }      
  for(j in 13:15) {
    v <- forInfo(f, "mark2")
    with(v, cat("index:", index, "bounds:", bounds, "\n"))
  }
  for(k in head(letters)) {
    v <- forInfo(f, "mark3")
    with(v, cat("index:", index, "bounds:", bounds, "\n"))
  }
}

f()
```

giving:

```
index: 1 bounds: 1 3 
index: 2 bounds: 1 3 
index: 3 bounds: 1 3 
index: 13 bounds: 13 15 
index: 14 bounds: 13 15 
index: 15 bounds: 13 15 
index: a bounds: a f 
index: b bounds: a f 
index: c bounds: a f 
index: d bounds: a f 
index: e bounds: a f 
index: f bounds: a f
```